# sed regex on multiple line can't capture all

Tags: regex, string, sed, multiline, regexp-replace

i have this text file (example)

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/>


<This is a line of text with a year=33020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=33020 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=33020 the month=2/>
```

using linux sed ( sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2) regexp:

```
 sed -En 'N;s/\<(This.*2020.*[\s\S\n]*?)\>/\1/gp' test2.txt
```

It capture only this string :

```
<This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
```

And i try to capture the first paragraph between < ..... > as group

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Could it be that `\<`  and `\>` are also sometimes used as word delimiters?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean that GNU sed regular expressions use `\<` and `\>` as word beginning and ending delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print paragraphs (delimited by `<...>`) starting with `<This`, containing `2020`, and only them, you could try:

```
sed -En '/^</!d;:a;/>$/!{N;ba;};/<This.*2020/p;' test2.txt
```

As long as the pattern space does not start with `<`, it is deleted and a new cycle is started (`/^</!d`).

Then, as long as the pattern space does not end with `>`, new lines are appended to it, but a new cycle is not started, instead we branch to the `a` label (`/>$/!{N;ba;}`).

When a full paragraph is stored in the pattern space we exit this loop and apply the last command (`^<This.*2020/p`): if the pattern space matches your pattern, it is printed. Finally, a new cycle starts.

Of course, the regular expressions must be adapted to your needs. If paragraph delimiters can be preceded (followed) by spaces, for instance, use:

```
sed -En '/^[[:space:]]*</!d;:a;/>[[:space:]]*$/!{N;ba;};/<This.*2020/p;' test2.txt
```

Comment: i fixed it with this  command : 
sed -i -En '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/<(This.*2020.*)\/>/<!--\1-->/p' test2.txt
but now i have new problem care to check ? 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662974/sed-command-succesfuly-find-and-replace-in-file-bit-erasing-everything-in-the

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Awk, you can specify `RS` to be a regular expression.

```sh
bash gawk -v RS='[<>]' /This.*2020/ <<\:
> <This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it This line of
> text does not have a year or month in it This year=2021 is the current
> year the current month=1 This is the year=2021 the month=2/>
> 
> <This is a line of text with a year=33020 month=12 in it This line of
> text does not have a year or month in it This year=33020 is the
> current year the current month=1 This is the year=33020 the month=2/>
> :
This is a line of text with a year=2020 month=12 in it
This line of text does not have a year or month in it
This year=2021 is the current year the current month=1
This is the year=2021 the month=2/
```

As you can see, this also trims the delimiter; but adding it back is not too hard (hint: `{ print "<" $0 ">" }`).